# Find max id from collection with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am trying to find max id from model.

My model is MainsliderStatu.

Here is My Code

```
$slider = new MainsliderStatu();
$slider = $slider->find($slider->select('MAX(id) AS id'));
$slider->statu = Input::get('statu');
$slider->save();
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Controller method not found.
```

I thing it cant find select method.

How can we do it?

Comment: why do you would like to get the max id? this is autoincrement. If you create a new model and save it, the id is automaticlly increment.

Comment: I want to get only max id from incremented.Have you any idea?

Comment: So, you create a model. Save it. And the you want to get the created model id?

Comment: You can use aggregates  http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#aggregates

Comment: @kotapeter Yes it is.

Comment: Your answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: @dyachenko When use aggregates I am getting this error:Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After save, $slider->id should be the last id inserted.

```
$slider = new MainsliderStatu();
$slider->statu = Input::get('statu');
$slider->save();

$slider->id;
```

If you would like to get back the latest `id` without create new model:

```
DB::table('mainslider_statu')->max('id');
```

Check if there isn't any row:

```
if(empty(MainsliderStatu::all()->toArray()))
{
    $slider = new MainsliderStatu();
    $slider->statu = Input::get('statu');
    $slider->save();

    $id = $slider->id;
} 
else 
{
    $id = DB::table('mainslider_statu')->max('id');
}
```

Comment: Infact I dont want to new insertion if row count bigger 0.

Comment: Getting This error:Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::order_by()

Comment: Ok but getting still this error:Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy()

Comment: There is no chance:Creating default object from empty value

Comment: Yes, if there isn't have any row, then you get back this message.

Comment: But there is a row in the table.

Comment: This is not solved and getting this error:Creating default object from empty value

Comment: This is solution:DB::table('mainslider_statu')->max('id');

Comment: Thanks anyway for your effort

Comment: Thanks! I edited my answer following by your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution:

```
    if(empty($slider->count())){



        $slider->statu = Input::get('statu');

        $slider->save();

        flash()->success('Slider Durumu Değiştirildi.');

        return Redirect::to('admin/mainslider');

    }else{

        $maxId = DB::table('mainslider_statu')->max('id');

        $slide = MainsliderStatu::find($maxId);

        $slide->statu = Input::get('statu');

        $slide->save();

        flash()->success('Slider Durumu Değiştirildi.');

        return Redirect::to('admin/mainslider');
        }
```

`DB::table('mainslider_statu')->max('id')` solved my problem.